# Any 2019 Grok NCSS

Tags: grok

Need help with the numbers in numbers and the any other problems from week 3 and 4 (like the flavour of the month one)

```
a = input('Search for: ')
b = int(input('In range up to: '))
expected_numbers = [i for i in range(b) if a in str(i)]
for i in expected_numbers:
    print(i,"contains",a)
```

Need a print saying 'Found X number(s) containing A between 1 and B

Answer (score 0):

for my code, I had two inputs and an empty list:

```
a = int(input("Search for: "))
b = int(input("In range up to: "))
found = []
```

I created a loop to check for all the numbers between 1 and b + 1 (plus 1 as it will check for all the number from 1 but not including b)

```
for i in range(1, b + 1):
```

I converted my inputs into strings so I could check if **a** was in **i**.

```
  if str(a) in str(i):
```

I created a variable to store my print statement:

```
    line = str(i) + " contains " + str(a)
```

This will print **line** for **i** in range of **b + 1**

```
    print(line)
```

I appended **i** to **found** so when I print **Found x number(s) containing x between 1 and (b + 1)**

```
    found.append(i)
```

I use ***len()*** to count all the items in **found**. I used an f string to make the print statement easier.

```
print(f'Found {str(len(found))} number(s) containing {str(a)} between 1 and {str(b)}.')
```

I hope this helps :)

All code:

```
a = int(input("Search for: "))
b = int(input("In range up to: "))
found = []
for i in range(1, b + 1):
  if str(a) in str(i):
    line = str(i) + " contains " + str(a)
    print(line)
    found.append(i)
print(f'Found {str(len(found))} number(s) containing {str(a)} between 1 and {str(b)}.')
```